# Partitions not recognized when installing Kubuntu 14.04 over complex RAID setup

Tags: raid, hard-drive, installation, partition, raid5

I have three identical HDDs. Using a ROM utility, I configured the use of 90% of each of them as a RAID 5 array, and the other 10% as a RAID 0 array. That is, each array uses some area on all three disks.

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 14.04 on this machine, but the installation partition selector/manipulator only seems to notice the small RAID 0 (striped) partition, not the bigger RAID 5 (parity) partition.

What do I do?